# I need to be able to print out an asterisk pattern asking the user to enter in the number of rows

Tags: python-3.x, image, for-loop, pycharm

1. Below is the pattern that needs to be correctly printed out.

   ```
   *****
   ****
   ***
   **
   *

   '''
   rows = int(input("Please enter the number of rows:"))

   for row in range(rows):
       for column in range(row + 1):
           print("*", end="")
       print()
   '''
   ```
2. Above is the reversed version. I'm trying to create the image shown at (1.)

Comment: `for row in range(rows, 0, -1)`. Have a look at the documentation for [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

Comment: No need for the second loop...  instead you can do 'print("*" * rows)'.  If you want to do fancier stuff, you can also take a look at the 'center' string method, which can do filling for you.